# Background execution of initial command in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up -d, I want to make each container start → shell run in the background.

I created docker-compose.yml as follows.

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: test:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    working_dir: /opt/test
    command: bash -c "./test.sh &"
```

However, when docker - compose up - d is executed, the container is created in exit state.

With the docker-compose up -d command alone, how can I do it in order to start containers → execute shell background through bash → detach?